# In an MS Word table, how to locate the cursor position and the mouse cursor position separately

Tags: vba, ms-word, cursor

I have a Word table in which I want to hide or reveal text in specific columns. I have written a macro linked to a check box in the header row. Ticking the box is supposed to hide the text in a column on the row where the cursor sits. The macro works fine when I test the VBA, but when I run it using the tick box, the code "thinks" the relevant row is the header row where the tick box resides.

How can I relay the correct row index (i.e. the row selected, where the text cursor sits, before the tick box is ticked) to the macro?

Maybe the correct question is: How does one differentiate between the cursor position in text (in a Word table) and the mouse cursor position?

Here is the macro code...

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Call HideOrRevealAnswer
End Sub

Sub HideOrRevealAnswer()

```
Dim iCellRange As Range
Dim iColStart, iColEnd As Integer
Dim iRow As Integer

iColStart = 4 'column for Answers
iColEnd = 5 'column for Explanation

With ActiveDocument
    iRow = Selection.Cells(1).RowIndex
    Set iCellRange = .Range(Start:=.Tables(1).Cell(iRow,iColStart).Range.Start, _
        End:=.Tables(1).Cell(iRow, iColEnd).Range.End)
    iCellRange.Select
End With

With iCellRange
    Select Case .Font.Color
        Case wdColorAutomatic
            .Font.Color = wdColorWhite
        Case wdColorWhite
            .Font.Color = wdColorAutomatic
    End Select
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing your code. Please edit a [mcve] into your question.

Comment: @Comintern I've added the macro code.

Comment: @Comintern Ok, I see I haven't given enough info to prompt an answer, or no-one has any idea either what I'm talking about or how to solve the problem. I'd include the cut-down Word document itself, with table, if I could work out how to upload it. Is this possible?